# UIWebView breaks website. What are my options?

Tags: uiwebview, safari

I have a UIWebView in my app.

When opening a specific Vimeo url the webpage looks broken.
In Safari the same page opens just fine.

What are my options?

Comment: You need to tweak few thing in UIWebView itself, to load a webpage inside app only this is the option which you have, alternately  you can open safari from your app if you want. For more help you need to add more details and attach screen shots what is the issue.

Comment: What things can I tweak in the UIWebView? The page just looks broken. Elements are going on top of each other - which in Safari it looks just fine.

Comment: Can you attach some screen shot or tell the url which you'r opening?